# Passing correct data values to bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

Having copied the code from the bootstrap modal examples,
I have a loop with a modal

```
@foreach (var member in chunkedmember)
{
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-link btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Groups
    </button> 
}
```

This creates a list of buttons and when the button is clicked I need to be able to access a property of member (member.Id).  It works, however it always returns the first member, not the one I am clicking.  How would I go about assigning each button to the correct member?

Comment: You are creating a bunch of identical buttons, how do you expect that any one of them will do something different?

Comment: I guess it's clear I'm very new to coding.  Could you suggest what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Explain exactly what you are trying to achieve and we will see what we can do!

Comment: The buttons will be next to the names of the group members.  When the button is clicked, it brings up the modal dialog which displays various properties of that member.  member has a property called member.Id, which is all I really need.  So I need to pass member.ID to the modal.

Comment: Sounds like you need to pass more than an ID unless you want an Ajax call to go back to the server to get the rest of the data?

Comment: No, all the other data has been passed in the viewmodel.  the critical statement within in the modal is this one:                              if (member.MemberId == Model.GroupSubscriptions.Groups[x].GroupMembers[i])                                               checkTest = "checked=\"checked\"";                                          Is this possibly a case where I need to do some javascript?

Comment: Remember that your MVC page is building up HTML to send to the browser. Once it has been sent, anything you haven't written out to the browser is NOT available without another HTTP call back to the server.